# wp capabilities edit own attachments

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

In my WordPress System I have two users 
- admin, id 1
- editor, id 2

If admin upload a file, admin and editor are able to edit the attachment, change fields like description

If editor uploads a file, neither admin nor editor are able to edit the attachment.

If I change the post_author in the database to "1", admin and editor are able to change the attachment???

I set the following capabilities in the functions.php Theme file:

```
$role = get_role('editor');
$role->remove_cap('edit_posts');
$role->remove_cap('moderate_comments');
$role->remove_cap('manage_categories');
$role->remove_cap('manage_tags');
$role->remove_cap('delete_pages');
$role->remove_cap('delete_others_pages');
$role->remove_cap('delete_published_pages');
```

Comment: Typically admin can edit any file..

Comment: edit_post capability use for editing file.You are removing it...therefore editor cant change it.. nor the admin.. if code runs in every time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
$role->remove_cap('edit_posts');
```

You can update the capabilities using this

```
$role->add_cap( 'edit_post' );
```

See [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this before. How can I update the capabilities after I removed this line?

Comment: You can use this plugin to manage capabilities easily.if you removed unknowingly 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/